# Como selecionar somente a classe sem a classe filha em javascript puro

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde, estou desenvolvendo um modal em javascript puro.
O que ocorre é o seguinte... o script detecta que existem tag com a classe "modal"`<div class="modal">`, e quando encontra uma ou mais ele insere as tags com as classes já definidas.
O que ocorre... uma das funções insere uma div dentro dessa div com a seguinte classe`<div class="modal loading"></div>` e dessa forma ele entra como mais um item dentro do laço do javascript.
Existe alguma forma de selecionar somente o modal que não tenha outra classe dentro?
 Eu estou usando essa chamada no meu javascript

```
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');
modal[i].innerHTML = "<div class='modal loading'></div>"
```

Meu CSS está dessa forma.

```
    .modal>.loading {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 10%;
    background: url(loader.gif) center no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode detectar usando `querySelector`, que retornará falso se não houver a `div` com a classe que você procura.

> A vantagem de usar `querySelectorAll` em vez de
>   `getElementsByClassName` é que o primeiro permite seletores CSS
>   completos.

```js
// aqui selecione apenas as divs com .modal sem .loading
var modal = document.querySelectorAll('div.modal:not(.loading)');

for(var item of modal){
   if(!item.querySelector("div.loading")){ // verifica se a div com a classe .loading existe dentro da modal
      console.log('A '+item.innerText+' não possui ".loading"');
   }
}
```

```css
/* Estilos apenas para ilustração */
div.modal:not(.loading){
   display: block;
   width: 100px;
   margin: 10px 0;
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
   <div class="modal loading">Loading</div>
   modal 1
</div>
<div class="modal">
   modal 2
</div>
<div class="modal">
   modal 3
</div>
<div class="modal">
   <div class="modal loading">Loading</div>
   modal 4
</div>
```

Comment: A resposta esta quase perfeita, só uma dúvida referente, existe alguma maneira no querySelectorAll de selecionar exatamente aquela uma classe ao invés de passar o parametro do :not()?

Comment: @김무진 Selecionando só .modal?

Comment: Perdão fui implementar o código adaptando a coisa esqueci de inibir o anterior, isso resolveu meu problema

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o pseudo selector `:not()`, no seu caso, para não selecionar a classe `.loading` você pode usar esse seletor:

```
.modal:not(.loading){

}
```

Comment: Meu problema é a seleção no javascript não no CSS